# Excel count based on values of 2 columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an Excel 2007 (xlsx) spreadsheet which has a table within it. The table has a column for date and a column for completed. I would like to do a count where the Date is today or earlier and where completed is not "Y"

The syntax I have put together is:

```
=COUNTIFS(UnitClosures[Completed Y/N], "<>Y", UnitClosures[Dismantling Date],"=< F7")
```

Cell `F7` contains today's date.

When I use this I get 0 back despite having multiple columns not set to completed with a date earlier than today.

How can I change the syntax of my formula to get it to work? 
Thanks!

Comment: change the last bit of your formula to `"<="&TODAY()`

Answer (score 6):

The final criterion syntax is wrong, F7 has to be outside the quotes and concatenated - try like this:

`"=<"&F7`

so formula becomes this:

`=COUNTIFS(UnitClosures[Completed Y/N], "<>Y", UnitClosures[Dismantling Date],"=<"&F7)`